# Share messages type among two project in Akka

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I am developing a reactive library that internally is implemented using Akka actors. Let's call this library `server`. The library exposes a single type of Actor as its API. This Actor accepts different types of messages, that define its public interface. Let's say that these messages are defined as the followings.

```
sealed trait Request
case class Creation(name: String) extends Request
sealed trait Response
case class CreationAck(name: String) extends Response
```

Now, I have to implement also a program that uses the above library. Let's call this program `client`. This program will also use Akka Actors to integrate with the library, for example using the *ask pattern* (the rest of the application is not developed using actors).

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
def create(): Future[CreationAck] = (mainActor ? Creation).mapTo[CreationAck]
// And so on...
```

Clearly, to let compiling to the above code, types `Creation` and `CreationAck` must be available both to `server` and to `client`.

My question is: Which is the best approach to share the public messages like `Creation` and `CreationAck` among the two projects? To build each program I am using *sbt*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package the messages with the `server` library, because the messages represent the library's public API. Any program that wishes to use this library could then import the necessary `server` packages and classes.

Creating a separate project for the messages could make sense if the messages were an interface that both `server` and `client` (and potentially others) implemented. But this is not the case, based on your description. Rather, the messages, and the implementation for which the messages are the API, are specifically tied to `server`. `client` doesn't *implement* these messages in any way; it's simply a user of the `server` library.

To reiterate the point, the messages are the public API of `server` and are tightly coupled to that library. The messages should be bundled with `server`.

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example of how to configure sbt and project structure to achieve what you said?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create another project (ex: `messages`) and implement these kinds of common objects and classes inside it.

Afterwards, import this library in which project you want to use. In your case, add it to your `build.sbt` files in both `server` and `client` projects.

By doing so, you will be able to use same classes in different projects.

Comment: So, I need to point phisically to the same code. I cannot replicate the same classes inside the `client` project, can I?

Comment: Yes, you will be pointing the same code. 
Replicating the same classes in different projects won't be the best practice for sure. And I am not sure if it is possible. Because to achieve this, you need to make sure that the package names are also same. Again, it is not the best idea.

Comment: That's ok. Using SBT, which approach do you suggest? I mean, is it better to have a subproject in `server` library or to have a completely separated project?

Comment: I would recommend creating a completely separate project.